# MySQL Query - set auto number

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many entries, starting with ID 100000 and ending at ID 200000.
Now I'm trying to set the first and lowest ID to 1, and decrease on each next ID +1

So the new first ID would be 1, and the last and highest would be 99000 in that example.

Is there any mysql query, which updates the rows from a given number, and +1 for each next row?

Comment: What about UPDATE your_table SET id=id-99999?

Comment: that is a good idea, but I was looking for something to set the first ID 100, and then +1 for each other next one

Comment: UPDATE your_table SET id=id-99900 :) SImple as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row number query in update and join with same table but update id with row number result from joined result set

```
update t
join ( 
select id,@r:=@r+1 `row`
from t 
cross join (select @r:=0) t1
) t2 on (t.id = t2.id)
set t.id = t2.row
```

> *Note: donot directly run this query on your production database first test it with a copy of your database if result is successful
>   then apply on production database*

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14ba9/1)